# How to parse .mbox format with delphi to delete mail attachments?

Tags: parsing, delphi, mbox

I would like to keep an archive of my e-mail conversations from the mailbox, but remove unnecessary attachments (which are usually graphics and text files), to make archive smaller. I wrote a simple parser that does for all downloaded mailboxes in a folder to remove anything that appears to be an attachment.

The code is very simple, and I think it can be done better. Besides, I don't know if I'm making a mistake or damaging the mbox file structure. Maybe there is a simpler method? Anyone could take a look at what I wrote?

- is there simplier way (maybe outside delphi, maybe some ready library)?
- can such code lead to irreversible damage to mbox format?
- can I lose some e-mails because of such a code?

Thanks a lot for any tips.

```
program ParseMailToClearTXT;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, StrUtils, Classes;

const mboxpath = 'e:\Downloads\Takeout\';

var FileIn, FileOut: TextFile;
    FileList: TstringList;
    Line, N_tmp: String;
    i: integer;

{ this is just a part for use to all files in directory }
procedure ListFileDir(Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if (SR.Attr <> faDirectory) then
      begin
        FileList.Add(SR.Name);
      end;
    until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
    FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;

begin

  FileList := TStringList.Create;
  ListFileDir(mboxpath,FileList);

  { ==== here starts parser ==== }

  for i := 0 to FileList.Count - 1
    do if pos('.mbox',FileList.Strings[i]) > 0
      then begin

  N_tmp := mboxpath+Trim(FileList.Strings[i]);
  Assign(FileIn, N_tmp);
  Assign(FileOut, N_tmp+'out.txt');
  Reset(FileIn);
  Rewrite(FileOut);

  repeat
    ReadLn(FileIn,Line);

    if (Pos('Content-Type: image',Line) > 0)
    or (Pos('Content-Type: application',Line) > 0)
    or (Pos('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8',Line) > 0)
    or (Pos('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"',Line) > 0)
    or (Pos('Content-Type: audio/mpeg',Line) > 0)
    or (Pos('Content-Type: application',Line) > 0)

      then begin
             WriteLn(FileOut, Line);
             repeat
               ReadLn(FileIn,Line);
             until (Length(Line) < 3) or (Eof(FileIn));
             ReadLn(FileIn,Line);
             WriteLn(FileOut, Line);
             repeat
               ReadLn(FileIn,Line);
             until (Length(Line) < 3) or (Eof(FileIn));
      end;

    if Pos('------',Line) > 0
      then begin
             WriteLn(FileOut, Line);
             repeat
               ReadLn(FileIn,Line);
             until {(Pos('From ',Line) > 0)
             or (Pos('filename',Line) > 0)}
             ((Pos('------',Line) > 0) and (RightStr(Line,2) = '--'))
             or (Eof(FileIn));
      end;
   WriteLn(FileOut, Line);
  until EOF(FileIn);
  CloseFile(FileIn);
  CloseFile(FileOut);
      end;
  FileList.Free;
end.
```

Comment: Recommendation questions are off topic here but you would be better off with, say, a python library, of which I am sure you have a choice

Comment: To answer your questions: Yes, such code can make you lose messages and permanently damage the mbox file. Nobody can guarantee that your code works, because the mbox "standard" is no standard but describes several similar formats.

Comment: `if Pos('------',Line) > 0` will break your neck, especially since you don't restrict it to only appear on the line's start but instead anywhere in it. If any password reset email has that string in its payload you'll end up ignoring many lines under a wrong assumption.